# Spec file not getting identified by Protractor cucumber framework

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

my Test config file is not able to find the spec file. i already have spec files created. previously i ran those scripts also.. but for more framework update i updated the paths of the files.. that makes spec files error and even i gave the full path also it is not able to find the spec file.

### Spec File

```
var utilityInit,page2//browser2;
page1=new facebook(firstBrowser);
module.exports=function(){
    this.Given(/^Open the browser and Load the URL$/,async function(){
        await firstBrowser.get(properties.get("url1"));
        browser.logger.info("Title of the window is :"+await browser.getTitle());
        //screenshots.takesScreenshot("filename");
    });
    
    this.When(/^User entered the text in the search box$/,async function(){
        firstBrowser.sleep(3000);
        await page1.email().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Username);
        browser.sleep(3000);
        await page1.password().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Password);
    });
    
    this.Then(/^click on login button$/,async function(){
        browser.sleep(3000);
        await facebook.submit().click();
    });
    
    this.Then(/^User tried to open in new browser instance$/,async function(){
        browser2=await openNewBrowser.newBrowserInit(firstBrowser);
        utilityInit=new utility(browser2);
        utilityInit.ignoreSync(properties.get("url2"));
        browser2.manage().window().maximize();
        console.log(await utilityInit.title()+" title");
        browser2.sleep(5000);
    });
    
    this.When(/^User entered the text in the email field$/,async function(){
        page2=new facebook(browser2);
        console.log(await page2.title()+" browser2");
        await page2.search().sendKeys("testing");
        browser2.sleep(3000);
        page1=new facebook(firstBrowser);
        console.log(await page1.title()+" browser1")
        await page1.email().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Username);
        screenshots.takeScreenshot("newScreenshot");
        firstBrowser.sleep(5000);
    })
}
```

### Config file

```
const log4js = require('log4js');
var fs=require('fs');
global.screenshots = require('protractor-take-screenshots-on-demand');
global.browser2;
var propertiesReader=require('properties-reader');

exports.config = {

//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
directConnect:true,

framework: 'custom',
// path relative to the current config file
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    metadata: {
        browser: {
            name: 'chrome',
            version: '79'
        },
        device: 'MacBook Pro 15',
        platform: {
            name: 'OSX',
            version: '10.12.6'
        },
       disableLog:true,
       durationInMS:true,
       openReportInBrowser:true
    }
},
ignoreUncaughtExceptions:false,
// Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
specs: [
    '../Proc/src/test/java/com/proc/features/test.feature'
],

beforeLaunch:function(){
    if (fs.existsSync('./logs/ExecutionLog.log')) {
        fs.unlink('./logs/ExecutionLog.log')
    }
    log4js.configure({
        appenders: {
            out: { type: 'console' }, 
            info:{ type: 'dateFile', filename: '../Reports/logs/info', "pattern":"-dd.log",alwaysIncludePattern:false},
            "console" : {
                "type": "console",
                "category": "console"
            },
            "file" : {
                "category": "test-file-appender",
                "type": "file",
                "filename": "../Reports/logs/log_file.log",
                "maxLogSize": 10240,
               // "backups": 3,
              //  "pattern": "%d{dd/MM hh:mm} %-5p %m"
            }
          },
         categories: {
               "info" :{"appenders": ["console"], "level": "info"},
               "default" :{"appenders": ["console", "file"], "level": "DEBUG"},
              //"file" : {"appenders": ["file"], "level": "DEBUG"}
        }
    });
},
cucumberOpts: {
    require:['../src/test/resources/com.proc.utility/timeOutConfig.js','../src/test/java/com/proc/TestCases/spec.js'],
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    format:'json:../Reports/jsonResult/results.json',
    'no-source': true
},
 onPrepare: function () {
     const logDefault = log4js.getLogger('default');
     const logInfo=log4js.getLogger('info');
     
     screenshots.browserNameJoiner = ' - '; //this is the default
     //folder of screenshot
     screenshots.screenShotDirectory = '../Screenshots';
     global.openNewBrowser=require("../src/test/resources/com.proc.utility/newBrowserinstance.js")
     global.testData=require("../TestData/testData.json");
     browser.logger = log4js.getLogger('protractorLog4js');
     global.firstBrowser=browser;
     global.properties=propertiesReader("../TestData/propertyConfig.properties");
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
     browser.manage().window().maximize();
     global.facebook=require("../src/test/java/com/proc/pages/fbPageObjects.js");
     global.utility=require("../src/test/resources/com.proc.utility/testFile.js");
  },
  plugins: [{
      package: '../Proc/node_modules/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin',
      options:{
          // read the options part for more options
          automaticallyGenerateReport: true,
          removeExistingJsonReportFile: true,
          reportPath:"../Reports/HtmlReports",
          reportName:"test.html"
      },
      customData: {
            title: 'Run info',
            data: [
                {label: 'Project', value: 'Framework Setup'},
                {label: 'Release', value: '1.2.3'},
                {label: 'Cycle', value: 'Test Cycle'}
            ]
        },
  }]
};
```

### Log

```
H:\workspace\Proc\Configuration>protractor testConfig.js
[23:38:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:38:00] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51680/devtools/browser/e9688f83-2047-4535-91ba-bf2100fe6016


0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
```

can some one please help me to clear this issue.. this is related to my project framework POC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a simple thing that makes my framework works.. 
`npm install cucumber@1.3.3 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify some other comments I have seen being made by others here, you do not have to give the exact file path. You can do

```
specs: [
'../Proc/src/test/java/com/proc/features/']
```

This path does not look correct to me ^ are you sure that is the correct path? also you have a javascript project but your file structure is a java structure `src/test/java` why?

Comment: Yes Reymond, i want to try the maven structure but it got flop.. if we didn't give the exact file path then how it run the feature file?

Comment: @SatishRongala Okay, I would recommend not using a Java structure in a javascript project as that is bad practice.  
To answer your question, it is a glob pattern https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/explaining-globs is a small explanation. Imagine you had 100 feature files! You would not want to list every single file, instead, you would pass in a glob and all the files that match the pattern would be included

Comment: okk and one more thing is "../../" relative path style is not working for me at all.. every time i am giving the full path then only it is working for the npm modules.. how can i overcome  that

Comment: @SatishRongala without seeing your full path structure I can't give an answer. Can you share the repo?

Comment: https://github.com/Satish152/Proc-UI ... i updated my folder structure to visual studio code format simply.. and also can you please look my code as it is not able to find the spec file even though it is present

Comment: I won't have time to go through all the code until this weekend but at a quick glance, try
`specs: [ '../features/']`

Comment: Thank you so much Raymond.. But please check it out if you get time..

Comment: Hi Raymond.. Please look in to it when ever you got the time..

Answer (score -1):

This because of the `Spec` path

```
specs: [
    '../Proc/src/test/java/com/proc/features/test.feature' //Provide a complete path to your test file along with file extension(.ts)
 ],
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: But while setting up a framework we need to provide relative path right.. So that it will be secure path and it took files from direct project folder

Comment: relative path is fine. Give the complete file along with the file extentsion(.ts or .js)

Comment: I gave the correct path with file extension.. I gave the feature file path for execution

Comment: great. Could you update the question with your implementation.

Comment: What you meant by implementation??

Comment: Could you update your project folder structure along with the test file name? in the question

Comment: Hi Madhan, please look in this question.. I updated my project structure..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981516/protractor-cucumber-configuration-file-throwing-undefined-warning-for-my-scenari

Comment: did you get a time to check that one..??

Comment: github.com/Satish152/Proc-UI hi madhan attached my repository url.. Can please try to look in to that code and please let me know why it is not able to find the spec file..